# In OS X Lion under zsh, how can I set up a /Users/username/tmp directory which deletes after X days?

Tags: osx-lion, zsh, cron

I'm new to scripting and regular jobs on OS X, so appreciate the help in advance.

I'm looking to have a tmp directory in my homedir, as in /Users/username/tmp which I can use as my "downloads" directory.

My goal is to have files/directories in this directory delete after say 10 days after the atime (last access).

So I am looking for a script and also the method to run it regularly on OS X Lion using ZSH as the shell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Write a script that deletes files in a folder if their atime is earlier than ten days ago, then have it run daily (I don't know what the best mechanism for that is on OSX; on Linux I'd use anacron, or failing that run it hourly with cron).

Sample script (takes the directory, eg ~/downloads, as first argument):

```
#!/bin/zsh

setopt extended_glob

targetpath=$1

[[ -d $targetpath ]] || (echo "Directory does not exist" 1>&2 && exit 1)

rm ${path}/**(.a+10) # ** will match recursively, and the bit in brackets is an
# extended glob qualifier, matching ordinary files with an atime more than ten days ago.
unsetopt extended_glob
exit 0
```

There's probably all sorts of things wrong with that, and if you habitually use extended_glob you don't need it turned on and later off in the script, naturally.

Comment: My understanding of `setopt` was that the option is set only in the current shell (and isn't saved anywhere), so you don't need to `unsetopt extended_glob` there (but unless you have `setopt` it in your `.zshenv`, you _will_ need to `setopt` it in the script).

Comment: @BlacklightShining Ah.  Good to know that failing to unsetopt it won't cause problems.  Thankee.

Comment: Usually `setopt`s go in `~/.zshrc`, which is _not_ read by `zsh` before executing scripts. Thus, you should always `setopt` options you need at the beginning of each script, like you did here. (Again, you don't need to `unsetopt` them, though.)

Comment: Yes, I gathered that it was definitely necessary to `setopt` them.